# jquery access json when keys are numbers

Tags: jquery, json

excuse my ignorance if this is obvious or answered before . I have a string like this

```
var test = {"99":{"ttop":"0","lleft":"0","wwidth":"881","hheight":"78"},
"42":{"ttop":"91","lleft":"110","wwidth":"285","hheight":"26"},
"43":{"ttop":"91","lleft":"490","wwidth":"117","hheight":"26"},
"44":{"ttop":"91","lleft":"5","wwidth":"87","hheight":"26"},
"36":{"ttop":"91","lleft":"630","wwidth":"251","hheight":"26"}}
```

I have read plenty about accessing with text identifiers (eg. "first-id" instead of "99") but I think my issue is that I get errors when I use a number for the id.

I Greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) as [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

```
test['99']
```

Comment: You can leave off the quotes if you like, the name will get coerced to a string.

Answer (score 1):

When the property name is not a valid identifier, use array syntax to access it:

```
test["99"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like that:

```
var biggestId = Object.keys(json).sort().pop();
console.log(test[biggestId]);
```

So you get value of biggest key in collection but it is data specific solution